# Разметка в SVG-файле

Tags: css, svg

Есть [SVG-файл](https://dev.shonada.com/local/templates/shotam/img/svg/down_quote.svg), который в CSS задается через `content`:

```css
.class:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: url(/local/templates/shotam/img/svg/down_quote.svg);
    top: -11px;
    left: -11px;
    background: #f6f6f6;
}
```

Как иконку сделать прозрачной и с серой обводкой в самом файле? То есть как применить свойства fill и stroke в xml-коде?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<svg id="v2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="45" height="45">
<path fill="none" stroke="gray" d="M 35.527302,19.633139 35.591817,7.9297372 24.364823,7.8831426 V 19.677216 h 5.418858 c -0.675637,2.814941 -1.080745,5.787947 -5.894695,6.127648 v 3.603207 l 5.210455,-0.0386 c 4.09538,-1.471228 6.575012,-7.351062 6.427855,-9.736338 z"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="gray" d="M 18.108444,19.633139 18.172959,7.9297373 6.945965,7.8831427 V 19.677216 h 5.418858 c -0.675637,2.814941 -1.080745,5.787947 -5.894695,6.127648 v 3.603207 l 5.210455,-0.0386 c 4.09538,-1.471228 6.575012,-7.351062 6.427855,-9.736338 z"></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Никак.

Из стилей html-страницы можно менять только то, что находится непосредственно на странице. Применить какие-либо стили к фону, подключенному из внешнего источника, невозможно.

Можно только поменять фон внутри самого svg-файла и сделать по картинке для каждого фона. Эти картинки можно объединить в файл-спрайт, если позволяет кроссбраузерность (насколько я помню, у некоторых браузеров были проблемы с svg-спрайтами и якорями на картинки в них).